# Renaming the output of a function (from inside the function) in R

Tags: r

I would like to improve an R function (that extracts an item from a nested list into a tibble column). My question is about how to rename programmatically the final output tibble, but I don't know how to do it inside the function itself.

Here is a toy dataset I created:

```
n_l <- list(
  doc1 = list (header = list ("bla1a", "bla1b"),
               metadata = list(dc = list (date = "2021",
                                          title = "Title 1")
               )
  ),
  doc2 = list (header = list ("bla2a", "bla21b"),
               metadata = list(dc = list (date = "2022",
                                          title = "Title 2")
               )
  ),
  doc3 = list (header = list  ("bla3a", "bla3b"),
               metadata = list(dc = list (date = "2023",
                                          title = "Title 3")
               )
  )
)
```

Here is my function:

```
library(tidyverse)

# FUNCTION: to turn a list item into a df column   --------------------------
function_n_l2t <- function(list, item_name ) {
  # 1) Prepare empty intermediate output
  item_l <- list(mode = "character", length = length(list))
  item_v <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(list))
  # 2)Loop to get the items as list, then vector
  for(i in seq_along(list)) {
    # extract ALL items LIST LIST
    item_l[[i]] <- list[[i]][["metadata"]][["dc"]][[item_name]]
    # transform list in vector
    item_v[[i]] <- unlist(item_l[[i]])
  }
  # 3) give desired name to output column / df
  column_name <- paste0("doc_mt_", item_name)
  # 4) transform vector in tibble
  item_t <- as_tibble_col(item_v, column_name =column_name)


}
```

Here  I execute the function. It works, but I only managed to rename the output tibble by executing the function from inside `assign`:

```
## input
list <- n_l
item_name <- "date"
df_name <- paste("col", item_name, sep = "_")

# ------------- CALL FUNCTION  (called INSIDE THE `assign`) ----------
## `assign` changes the name of output on the fly
assign(df_name, value = function_n_l2t(list, item_name ))
```

Is there a more elegant/safe way to rename the output tibble from inside the function itself?

Comment: I don't think I'm following. Why would you want to do that if variable names inside of a function are all placeholders anyways?

If you just want to move the naming logic to inside the function, you could add a field in your output with that info, and use that field to rename it outside of the function with assign?

As a usage note, function names should be verbs/verb phrases. `function_n_l2t` seems less clear than `transform_list_to_tibble`. The function name absorbs the info of the comment above it, and you can use the comment to instead explain how/why it performs that action.

Comment: @Jeff, tx for the advice. The reason is that I will need to run the same function for many items in my nested list so I wanted to have it spit out the final output. With `df_name <- paste("col", item_name, sep = "_")`  inside the function I get an error that "df_name" doesn't exist. My ultimate goal would be a function that iterate the same for all the items in metadata (`n_l[["doc1"]][["metadata"]][["dc"]][["title"]]` and `n_l[["doc1"]][["metadata"]][["dc"]][["date"]]`) but that is beyond my programming level 